# How to fix Unity 3d "error CS1703: An assembly `System.Xml.Linq' with the same identity has already been imported."

Tags: .net, xml, linq, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm stuck here and I dont know how to fix this. I update my Unity to Unity 2017.1.0f3 and updated/upgraded my project now I'm getting this error:

> Error CS1703: An assembly `System.Xml.Linq' with the same identity has
>   already been imported. Consider removing one of the references
>   Assets/Plugins/System.Xml.Linq.dll *(Location of the symbol related to
>   previous error)* C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\System.Xml.Linq.dll
>   *(Location of the symbol related to previous error)*

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it means that two dlls have the same signature.  In my code, it was nunit.framework.dll appeared in two different folders and were imported.  NOTE: The names are not the same --> one was called nunit.framework.dll and the other was 123nunit.framework.dll. However, their signature seems to be the same.  I suspect that 123nunit.framework.dll was purchase out of the Unity Store and nunit.framework.dll is now part of Unity.

This occurred on updating from 5.1 to 2017.1

Hope this helps.